How to align elements to flush between the start of my logo and end of links
[Hi everyone I have been trying to figure out how to align my code for fews days now. I would like my html after my header to be between my logo and links. The goal is not to use padding as after a certain screen size I would like to keep the same layout.
I tried using justify content space-around in my flex class but it won't line up. I tried giving the div in my flex class a width and played around with other values but it didn't solve. I appreciate any help given, thank you in advance.


body {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

.section-one {
  background-color: blue;
  color: white;
  padding: 50px 0;
}

.header {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-around;
  padding: 0 0 50px 0;
}

ul {
  display: flex;
  gap: 1rem;
  margin: 0;
  list-style: none;
}

.flex {
  display: flex;
  gap: 20px;
}

.column,
.placeholder-image {
  flex: 1;
  flex-direction: column;
  border: 5px solid;
}
<section class="section-one">
  <div class="header">

    <div class="logo left">LOGO</div>

    <div class="right">
      <ul>
        <li>
          <a href=""></a>link one</li>
        <li>
          <a href=""></a>link two</li>
        <li>
          <a href=""></a>link three</li>

      </ul>
    </div>

  </div>
  <div class="flex">

    <div class="column">
      <div>
        <h1>This website is awesome</h1>
      </div>
      <div>
        <p class="quote">Lorem ipsum, dolor sit amet elit. Laboriosam, eum blanditiis porro ad animi aliquam, quisquam dolore nisi eaque sit explicabo laborum voluptatibus.</p>
      </div>
      <div><button class="sign-up">sign up</button></div>
    </div>
    <div class="placeholder-image">This is a place holder for an image

    </div>
  </div>
</section>




That space around header text, is a dynamic padding which is comin after rendering. If you want to rely on that, you need JavaScript to get the calculated size after rendering.

What do you mean by between the logo and links ?

Please clarify your specific problem or add additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it’s hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

@Symtox  I have added an image. I would my information in between those black lines.

Here is a simple approach using some padding. I also changed the space-around  to space-between in order to have the header's elements at the edges


header {
  justify-content: space-between;
  margin-bottom: 1rem;
}

header,
main {
  padding-inline: 2rem;
  display: flex;
}

ul {
  list-style: none;
  display: flex;
  gap: 10px;
}

main {
  gap: 10px;
}

.image {
  width: 30px;
  height: 30px;
  background: pink;
}

.left, .right {
  flex-basis: 50%;
  outline: 1px solid blue;
}
<header>
  <div class="image"></div>
  <ul class="links">
    <li>Link1</li>
    <li>Link2</li>
    <li>Link3</li>
  </ul>  
</header>
<main>
  <div class="left">
    <h1>This website is awesome</h1>
    <p class="quote">Lorem ipsum, dolor sit amet elit. Laboriosam, eum blanditiis porro ad animi aliquam, quisquam dolore nisi eaque sit explicabo laborum voluptatibus.
    </p>
    <button class="sign-up">sign up</button>
  </div>
  <div class="right">
    This is a place holder for an image
  </div>
</main



Edit: you have a lot of useless divs in your left column

glad I could help !
